# Can a class of arithmetical statements containing its own soundness condition be closed under negation?

Tags: lo.logic

Given a class $C$ of arithmetical sentences, 
an arithmetical theory $T$ is said to be $C$-sound if 
all the theorems of $T$ which are in $C$ are true. 
For instance, $T$ is $\Sigma_1$-sound if all the $\Sigma_1$ theorems of $T$ are true.

Now, for some classes $C$, like the class of $\Sigma_1$ sentences, 
the statement "$T$ is $C$-sound" is expressible in the language of arithmetic.
For other classes, like the class of all arithmetical sentences, $C$-soundness 
(which is just soundness) can't be definable in the language of arithmetic.
But there are some classes, like the class of $\Pi_1$ sentences, 
which have a rarer property: 
not only is $C$-soundness definable in the language of arithmetic, it can be defined within $C$ itself.

However, I'm looking for an even rarer property:

> does there exist a class $C$ for which 
>   $C$-soundness is definable within $C$, *and* 
>   which is also closed under negation?

Or, failing that:

> does there exist a class $C$ for which 
>   "$T$ is **not** $C$-sound" is expressible within $C$?

Comment: Could you clarify the contet of $T$? I had thought of it as fixed, but when you refer to expressing "$T$ is $C$-sound", it seems perhaps that you treat it more like a variable. After all, if $T$ is a true theory, then $T$ is $C$-sound for every $C$. For example, the empty theory is always $C$-sound for every $C$. So these would seem to be expressible by any tautology. But that wouldn't seem to be what you want; so I am unsure exactly what you want.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins When I talk about C-soundness being definable in the language of arithmetic, I mean that "T is C-sound" is expressible in the language of arithmetic for all arithmetical theories T.

Comment: If $T$ is arithmetical of even moderate complexity, then why should the assertion that $T$ is $\Pi_1$-sound be $\Pi_1$-expressible? Or are you only considering computably-axiomatizable theories rather than arithmetically axiomatizable theories? Also, I still find it unclear what you mean by saying "$T$ is $C$-sound" is expressible, since $T$ is a theory and not a number variable. Do you mean, given a number that is a TM program $p$ that accepts a theory, then the assertion "the theory accepted by program $p$ is $C$-sound" is expressible as a formula in variable $p$?

Comment: I don't even know what "arithmetically axiomatizable" means.  I'm just talking about recursively axiomatizable theories in the language of first-order arithmetic.  As far as what I mean by C-soundness being expressible, yes we can say that "the theory encoded by p is C-sound" is expressible as an arithmetical formula in p.

Comment: That's fine, and restricting to computably axiomatizable theories resolves all my issues. An arithmetically axiomatizable theory, in contrast---and this is what I had thought you meant by an "arithmetic theory"---is a theory with an arithmetically definable set of axioms; that is, it is $\Sigma^0_n$-axiomatizable for some $n$ rather than $\Delta^0_1$-axiomatizable as with computably axiomatizable theories. The theory of true arithmetic assertions, for example, is not arithmetically axiomatizable by Tarski's theorem, but of course any computably axiomatizable theory is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to both questions is negative.

**Theorem.** There is no class $C$ of formulas in the language of
arithmetic, such that
the assertion "$T$ is not $C$-sound" is uniformly expressible in $C$
for c.e. theories $T$ (regarded as an index of $T$ as a c.e. set).

Proof. Suppose $C$ is like that. By the Gödel fixed-point lemma, there is a sentence $\psi$
such that $$\text{PA}\vdash\psi\longleftrightarrow
(\ \{\text{PA}+\psi\}\text{ is not }C\text{-sound }).$$ The assumption on $C$ ensures that the
assertion "$T$ is not $C$-sound" is expressible in $C$, and so it follows that
$\psi$ is PA-provably equivalent to a sentence in $C$, and we may
assume without loss that $\psi$ is actually in $C$.

On the one hand, if $\psi$ is true, then $\text{PA}+\psi$ is true
and therefore also sound, since every true theory is sound. But
since $\psi$ asserts that $\text{PA}+\psi$ is not $C$-sound, and
since this assertion is in $C$, then it must be true that
$\text{PA}+\psi$ is not sound, a contradiction.

On the other hand, if $\psi$ is false, then because $\psi$ is in
$C$, it is true that $\text{PA}+\psi$ is not $C$-sound. But in
this case, $\psi$ would be true, contrary to our assumption. QED

Comment: Thanks @JoelDavidHamkins!  I suspected that Tarski's theorem would be involved.  In fact, the whole reason I asked this question was trying to see what would happen if you restricted soundness to some arithmetically definable C-soundness property, but it looks like there's no evading the logic of Tarski.